# Send sensor data to update rviz model

Tags: ros2, rviz, beginner, tf

I'm completely new to ROS(2) and I want to make my Robot Model in RViz move depending on sensordata. I build my files according to a minimal working example from youtube and it allows me to visualize my project in RViz an manipulate the joint with the `joint_state_publisher` with my computermouse, but I want to make it subscribe to sensordata, therefore I tried to manipulate the joint using:

```
ros2 topic pub /tf tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage '{transforms: [{header: {stamp: {sec: 0, nanosec: 0}, frame_id: "start_frame"}, child_frame_id: "end_frame", transform: {translation: {x: 1.0, y: 2.0, z: 2.0}, rotation: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.5}}}]}'
```

in the Terminal and I when I subscribe to the `joint_state_publisher_gui` I can see, that the values change accordingly for a fraction of a second but are then overwritten again from the `joint_state_publisher`.

`CMakeLists.txt`:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(smartjig_urdf)

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)

    #selbst hinzugefügt, zur Not entfernen
        find_package(ament_cmake_python REQUIRED)    
        find_package(rclpy REQUIRED)
    #selbst hinzugefügt, zur Not entfernen



install(
    DIRECTORY launch urdf
    DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}
    )

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # comment the line when a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # comment the line when this package is in a git repo and when
  # a copyright and license is added to all source files
  set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()
```

`display.launch.py`:

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    pkgPath = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='smartjig_urdf').find('smartjig_urdf')
    urdfModelPath= os.path.join(pkgPath, 'urdf/smartjig.urdf')
    
    with open(urdfModelPath,'r') as infp:
        robot_desc = infp.read()
        
    params = {'robot_description': robot_desc}
    
    robot_state_publisher_node =launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[params])
    
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
        parameters=[params],
        condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        name='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )
    
    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen'
    )
    
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='gui', default_value='True',
                description='This is a flag for joint_state_publisher_gui'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=urdfModelPath,
                description='Path to the urdf model file'),
    robot_state_publisher_node,
    joint_state_publisher_node,
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
    rviz_node
    ])
```

`package.xml`:

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    pkgPath = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='smartjig_urdf').find('smartjig_urdf')
    urdfModelPath= os.path.join(pkgPath, 'urdf/smartjig.urdf')
    
    with open(urdfModelPath,'r') as infp:
        robot_desc = infp.read()
        
    params = {'robot_description': robot_desc}
    
    robot_state_publisher_node =launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[params])
    
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
        parameters=[params],
        condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        name='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )
    
    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen'
    )
    
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='gui', default_value='True',
                description='This is a flag for joint_state_publisher_gui'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=urdfModelPath,
                description='Path to the urdf model file'),
    robot_state_publisher_node,
    joint_state_publisher_node,
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
    rviz_node
    ])
```

`smartjig.urdf`:

```
import launch
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
import launch_ros
import os

def generate_launch_description():
    pkgPath = launch_ros.substitutions.FindPackageShare(package='smartjig_urdf').find('smartjig_urdf')
    urdfModelPath= os.path.join(pkgPath, 'urdf/smartjig.urdf')
    
    with open(urdfModelPath,'r') as infp:
        robot_desc = infp.read()
        
    params = {'robot_description': robot_desc}
    
    robot_state_publisher_node =launch_ros.actions.Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    output='screen',
    parameters=[params])
    
    joint_state_publisher_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher',
        executable='joint_state_publisher',
        name='joint_state_publisher',
        parameters=[params],
        condition=launch.conditions.UnlessCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        name='joint_state_publisher_gui',
        condition=launch.conditions.IfCondition(LaunchConfiguration('gui'))
    )
    
    rviz_node = launch_ros.actions.Node(
        package='rviz2',
        executable='rviz2',
        name='rviz2',
        output='screen'
    )
    
    return launch.LaunchDescription([
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='gui', default_value='True',
                description='This is a flag for joint_state_publisher_gui'),
        launch.actions.DeclareLaunchArgument(name='model', default_value=urdfModelPath,
                description='Path to the urdf model file'),
    robot_state_publisher_node,
    joint_state_publisher_node,
    joint_state_publisher_gui_node,
    rviz_node
    ])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change those values, you'd need to stop the joint state publisher so that you can override them in rviz. Keep in mind Rviz is just a visualizer, its not a simulator like gazebo. Its only showing you what's going on over the messages / transforms.

Most practically, you'd want to make your own joint state publisher script so that you can manipulate it if you want to move it (visually speaking). I believe there are examples of this in MoveIt where they have sliders that you can move joints in an arm with a QT application to make your robot do something in an Rviz display. But obviously this is just one example, you're free and encouraged to do something more specific for your needs / tests.

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to write a ROS node that reads in your sensor data with a joint states publisher. Based off your sensor reading, you can publish the joint behavior you'd like. Then replace your `joint_state_publisher` and `joint_state_publisher_gui` nodes in launch file with this node you just made.

They'll be tutorials in the ROS documentation but here are the key parts to having a custom joint state publisher:

```
custom_jsp = this->create_publisher<sensor_msgs::msg::JointState>(
        "topic_name",
        rclcpp::QoS(1));
```

```
sensor_msgs::msg::JointState joint_states_msg;
joint_states_msg.header.stamp = this->get_clock()->now();
joint_states_msg.name = {
    "link_name", // That matches your robot_description
};
joint_states_msg.position = {
    0.0, // Position effected by sensor data, from another loop in your node
};
custom_jsp->publish(joint_states_msg);
```

Let me know if this helps!